# C# - interop excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, excel-interop

I want to filling windows form data to excel. the end of code I give validation so if the filename exist on specific location it would not save it again

```
string savingNewForm = "C:\\temp\\" + temp;
            if (File.Exists(savingNewForm))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File already exist!");
                oBook.Close();
                oApp.Quit();
            }
            else
            {
                oBook.SaveAs(savingNewForm);
                oBook.Close();
                oApp.Quit();
                MessageBox.Show("Your file saved");
            }
```

but when user save the same filename it give error.

I think the main problem is on `if (File.Exists(savingNewForm))` cause it's not checking if the filename exist or not, instead it goes to `else` and give a popup excel asking if I want to replace or not.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: can you show me your

Comment: You say "it give error" - what error? What line?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `temp`? There could be a problem if the filename contains invalid characters or is too long, etc.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Exists method should not be used for path validation, this method
>   merely checks if the file specified in path exists. Passing an invalid
>   path to Exists returns **false**.
>
> If path describes a directory, this method returns **false**.
>
> The Exists method returns **false** if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists.

If the directory doesn't exist or if the user does not have permission to read the file (maybe it's locked) then `File.Exists()` will return false.

Comment: temp value are the firstname and lastname that user input on text box, so it will become filename

Answer (score 0):

If it's an issue with the existence of the file, see Softerware's answer.  If you want Excel to not ask the user to overwrite, try:

```
oApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I haven't worked with your excel library, suggest you to try workaround:

- save into another file;
- remove target;
- move saved file to target filename.

Error on file removing will be more informative anycase.